# PHP MySQL PDO: Weird looping when calculate momentum indicator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to calculate momentum indicator from imported csv file which is stock market historical data.
I made 'momentum_data' table which contains 'Date, Close, Close14, Momentum' columns.
And the problem I got is to insert my data to momentum_data table from php with PDO.

The closest aproach I made was using this code:

```
foreach ($sql as $data) {
$tanggal = $data['Date'];
$close = $data['Close'];
$close[] = $data['Close'];
$jumlah = count($close);
$momentum= 0;

        for($i=14;$i<$jumlah;$i++){
          $close1 = $close[$i-14];
          $momentum = $close[$i]/$close1*100;

  $sql2->bindParam(':close14', $close);
  $sql2->bindParam(':Date', $tanggal);
    $sql2->bindParam(':close', $close1);
    $sql2->bindParam(':momentum', $momentum);
    $sql2->execute();}}
```

and queries:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM csv_data ORDER BY Date");
```

$sql->execute();
and

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO momentum_data VALUES (:Date,:close,:close14,:momentum)");
```

The data were inserted to database, but the data duplicated based on what row the data are. 
the output will look like this

```
|no|data1|data2|
|1 |1    |1    |
|2 |2    |2    |
|2 |2    |2    |
|3 |3    |3    |
|3 |3    |3    |
|3 |3    |3    |
```

Is there something wrong in my code (obviously). 
Any helps or hints would be really apreciated.
Sorry for terrible english.

Comment: prepare the query and bind the parameters outside the loop

Comment: @RamRaider I indeed put the query outside loop. If I bind parameters outside the loop, It will only insert the last data from looping.

Answer (score 0):

By `preparing` the query and `binding` the parameters outside the loop you simply need reassign the variables within the loop before executing the statement ~ though I found the naming of variables here a little confusing.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into `momentum_data` (
```

`date`, `close`, `close14`, `momentum` ) values ( :date, :close, :close14, :momentum )");
    if( $stmt ){

```
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $tanggal );
    $stmt->bindParam(':close', $close1 );
    $stmt->bindParam(':close14', $close );
    $stmt->bindParam(':momentum', $momentum );


    $sql='select * from `csv_data` order by `date`;';
    $results=$conn->query( $sql );

    $tmp=array();/* it was confusing having $close and $close[] */


    while( $rs=$results->fetch_object() ){

        $tanggal    = $rs->date;
        $close      = $rs->close;
        $tmp[]      = $rs->close;
        $jumlah     = count( $tmp );
        $momentum   = 0;


        for( $i=14; $i < $jumlah; $i++ ){
            $close1 = $tmp[ $i-14 ];
            $momentum = $tmp[ $i ] / $close1 * 100;
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```